# SED for thousand of 301 redirections on htaccess?

Tags: text-processing, sed, htaccess

I got a headache with URLS after change them on one of my websites.
The URLs were very long and I decided to change them despite the later change via .htacces...

I'm making the change one by one (I have more than 1500 URLs...)

I have this:

```
Redirect 301 /noticies/festes-noticies/diania-roda-les-aixames-la-nit-de-nadal/
```

And this becomes:

```
Redirect 301 /noticies/festes-noticies/diania-roda-les-aixames-la-nit-de-nadal/ /diania-roda-les-aixames-la-nit-de-nadal/
```

The last `/-----/`, were put at the finish of the line, with one blank space.

There are a method with sed or another command to do this easily?

Answer (score 1):

is `sed` mandatory ?

```
awk -F/ '{printf "%s /%s/\n",$0,$(NF-1)}' old_file > new_file
```

to apply only to line with redirect and rewrite a full file.

```
awk -F/ '$1 ~ /Redirect/ {printf "%s /%s/\n",$0,$(NF-1); next ; } {print}' old_file > new_file
```

where

- `-F/` tell awk to use `/` as field separator
- `$0` , `$(NF-1)` are whole line, before the last field
- `$1 ~ /Redirect/` select line with redirect
- `next` go to next line
- `{print}` implicit print of line not matching `Redirect`

Edit: if original line end up with a trailling `/`, we need to pick before-the-last field.

---

note some `awk` can edit in place (`awk -i`); however I would suggest you keep original file and apply edition to a new file, and rename it if you are satisfied by the result.

Comment: I try both, but I get this: 

    Redirect 301 /noticies/el-travafest-reviu-lactivitat-festiva-a-millena-amb-cultura-popular/ //

Only the inside is missing. The result should be: 

  

    Redirect 301 /noticies/el-travafest-reviu-lactivitat-festiva-a-millena-amb-cultura-popular/ /el-travafest-reviu-lactivitat-festiva-a-millena-amb-cultura-popular/

Comment: sorry, I replace `$NF` by `$(NF-1)` , can you give a try ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
< input_file sed -E 's#((/[^/]*){2})$#\1 \1#' > output_file
```

- `/[^/]*` matches a slash followed by zero or more characters without a slash.
- `(){2}` means the expression into parentheses twice.
- `$` matches the end of line.
- The outer `()` allows to reuse what's inside as `\1` into the replacement part.
- Also a character different from slash, like `#`, is being used as separator into this substitution, for convenience. And `-E` enables EREs.